# python unicode to list, reciving double double quotes

Tags: python, list, unicode

I'm doing some fetching via tornado websocket and recive json data like this:

```
msg = [157,"tu","27213579-SD",229156181,1524173145,8265,0.08]
```

type(msg) -> unicode

now I have to convert it into datatype list.
My first intention was the following:

```
msg = [e.encode('utf-8') for e in msg.strip('[]').split(',')]
```

but now there are double quotes

```
msg =["157",""tu"",""27213579-SD"","229156181","1524173145","8265","0.08"]
```

Do you know a smart way to get a clean python list?

Comment: This looks like JSON

Comment: Is that a python statement? How did you get `<type...>` to display? As shown, that's a python list. If its actually in a string, show that instead.

Comment: ...and where are these double double quotes? Showing the problem in the python shell and then copying that full session here can be helpful.

Comment: This question doesn't have enough information to give an answer. Lets close for lack of detail.

Comment: sorry, I have revised my question. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Problem solved! json.loads(msg) is the function I have looking for. There is also a difference between json.load and json.loads, so if you have the same problem, take care that you aren't missing the s!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `json` module to convert JSON to data:

```
#!python2
import json

msg = u'[157,"tu","27213579-SD",229156181,1524173145,8265,0.08]'
print type(msg)
data = json.loads(msg)
print type(data)
print data
```

Output:

```
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'list'>
[157, u'tu', u'27213579-SD', 229156181, 1524173145, 8265, 0.08]
```